# Using the Weierstrass M-test properly,

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am slightly confused by the last part of my work here.  For $x>0$ and for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$,

$$\left |\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}\right |$$

$$=\left |\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x}+nx)n^{\alpha}}\right |$$

$$\le\left |\frac{1}{(nx)n^{\alpha}}\right |$$

$$\le \frac{1}{xn^{1+\alpha}}$$

and now I claim that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{xn^{1+\alpha}}<\infty$$

by the p-series / integral tests, and so

$$\sum\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}$$ converges uniformly (to a continuous function of $x$ >0) by the Weierstrass M-test.

Is my claim correct?  The $\large \frac{1}{x}$ factor in the summand confuses me a little bit; but, it is *fixed*, so I don't think it affects the convergence of the p-series.

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot keep any $x$ in your upperbound: it must be a function of $n$ (and the constant $\alpha$) only.

Comment: Really, you should tell us the problem you're working on, not just the "last part".

Comment: The $\frac1x$ factor in the summand doesn't affect the convergence for any fixed $x$. However, it does prevent us from saying the convergence is uniform in $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification, @robjohn :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited** to point out that we actually have uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb R$, not just $(0,\infty)$.

---

Observe that
$$0 \leq (\sqrt{n}|x| - 1)^2 = nx^2 - 2\sqrt{n}|x| + 1$$
so
$$1 + nx^2 \geq 2\sqrt{n}|x|$$
and therefore,
$$\frac{|x|}{1 + nx^2} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
Consequently, for all $x \in \mathbb R$ we have
$$\left|\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}\right| = \frac{|x|}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}
\leq \frac{1}{2n^{\alpha + 1/2}}$$
Now, observe that the right hand side does not depend on $x$, and its sum converges since $\alpha > 1/2$. So you can conclude from the Weierstrass $M$-test that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}$$
converges uniformly for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Among other things, this allows us to conclude that the limit function
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}$$
is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Bungo :-)  I was instead going to show the uniform convergence on compact sets [$\epsilon, R$], and then let $\epsilon$ be arbitrarily small, and similarly, let $R$ be arbitrarily large.  With the $\epsilon$ and $R$, I could get a uniform bound easily (on compact sets).  But your upper bound avoids that (shaky?) argument :-)

Comment: @User001: In case you didn't happen to notice the trick involving the quadratic, a more general technique would be to differentiate the summand to find its maximum (also check to make sure that the maximum doesn't occur at one of the endpoints of the domain). In other words, what Clement C. suggested in his answer.

Comment: Ok got it, @Bungo.  I definitely did not notice the trick, although I have seen it come up *a lot* by now.  Hopefully I'll notice it by myself next time on a similar problem.  BTW, would my argument work?  Showing the uniform convergence first on compact sets, and then letting epsilon be arbitrarily small, R be arbitrarily large.  I still have...compact sets, I think.  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: I don't think it would work, at least not in this case, because the maximum of the $n$'th term occurs at $x = 1/\sqrt{n}$ (as you can verify by plugging in $x=1/\sqrt{n}$ and simplifying). So no matter what $\epsilon$ you choose, the $x$ value corresponding to the maximum would fall outside $[\epsilon, R]$ for sufficiently large $n$. Therefore, showing uniform convergence on $[\epsilon, R]$ for every $\epsilon$ would not necessarily imply uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Actually just one more quick question, if you don't mind @Bungo :-)  Since we found a uniform bound, and the sum of this bound is convergent (convergent p-series), then is there a discrete analog to the Dominated Convergence Theorem, so that $lim_{x->0} \sum f(x) = \sum lim_{x->0} f(x) = \sum 0 = 0$?  I would guess that this is legitimate...what do you think?  I have yet to see a theorem in the continuous case *not* have a discrete analog.  E.g. Tonelli's theorem for double summations is the discrete analog to Fubini's Theorem, among many other examples.  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: Hmm, there might be such a formulation. But you don't really need that. We established uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$, but we could equally well have done it on $[0,\infty)$, because the bound for the $n$'th term, $1/n^{\alpha  +1/2}$, is valid for $x=0$ as well. Then, since the partial sums are continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and the convergence is uniform on $[0,\infty)$, we know that the sum of the series, let's call it $F(x)$, is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Therefore, $\lim_{x \to 0}F(x) = F(0) = 0$.

Comment: @User001: In fact, the bound $1/n^{\alpha + 1/2}$ works for all $x \in \mathbb R$ since the terms of the sum are odd functions. So you actually have uniform convergence everywhere, and the resulting sum $F(x)$ is continuous everywhere. I will edit to point this out.

Comment: Hi @Bungo, sorry, I promise this is the last question:  what if $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$?  The last part of the problem statement asks to consider this case and to show that $lim_{x->0} F(x)>0$.  But using our bound from before, the sum of the bound is now the (divergent) harmonic series ... what approach can I take for the case $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: Right, I think the convergence will not be uniform in case $\alpha = 1/2$, so that case will have to be treated differently. To avoid extended discussion in comments, I suggest that you create a new question and link it to this one. If I don't get a chance to answer I'm sure someone will :-)

Comment: Ok, got it - I have just posted the question.  Thanks so much for your help; hope to hear from you soon!  Have a great night @Bungo :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot keep any $x$ in the upper bound -- you are looking for a *uniform* upperbound on $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n^\alpha(1+nx^2)}$, i.e. something of the form
$$
\exists (M_n)_{n\geq 1} \text{ s.t. }\forall n\geq 1, \forall x > 0,\ \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leq M_n; \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty
$$
Here, your $M_n$ depends on $x$: this is not legit. A way to solve your problem would be to see if, for every $n\geq 1$, $\lvert f_n\rvert$ can be maximized by some value $x_n >0$; and set $M_n = \lvert f_n(x_n)\lvert$.

For instance, studying the function $f_n$ (and differentiating it), it appears that $f_n=\lvert f_n\rvert$ is maximized at $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. If you take $M_n = \lvert f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\lvert$, you do get (by construction!) $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leq M_n$ for all $x>0$. But then, it only remains to check whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks so much @ClementC :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a similar fashion to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581857), we see, using the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\,x^{1-2\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}x^{2\alpha}}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)t^\alpha}\\[6pt]
&=\Gamma(1-\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi\alpha)}
\end{align}
$$
and we can bound
$$
\frac{\pi x^{2\alpha-1}}{\sin(\pi\alpha)}-\frac{x}{1-\alpha}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}\le\frac{\pi x^{2\alpha-1}}{\sin(\pi\alpha)}
$$