# Show that this limit is positive,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I want to show that, for $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}>0$$

Any ideas are welcome.

(In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581690/using-the-weierstrass-m-test-properly), I considered the case for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$, from which we were able to derive a uniform upper bound and use Weierstrass M-test and Dominated Convergence Theorem to establish the continuity of the series and evaluate the limit as $x \to 0$)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $x$, it can be seen that this is a Riemann Sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}x}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}\\[6pt]
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$

---

**Convergence of the Riemann Sum**

In comparison to the curve $\frac1{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}$, the sum above is the sum of the area of the rectangles below whose widths are $x^2$.

[image]

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}x}
&\le\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}\\
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$
However, if we shift the rectangles right by $x^2$,

[image]

we see that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}x}
&\ge\int_{x^2}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}\\
&\ge\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}
-\int_0^{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t}}\\[6pt]
&=\pi-2x
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\pi-2x\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}x}\le\pi
$$

Comment: Would be good if you mentioned why the infinite Riemann sums converge to the value of the improper integral.

Comment: @zhw.: so mentioned.

Comment: Hi @robjohn, nice to hear from you and thanks for your pretty solution.  Can I ask you a couple of follow-up questions?  How come you start the integration at zero, when the Riemann sum had started at n=1?  And how did you know the integration interval would be the entire positive half line, and not some smaller interval [a,b]?

Comment: And one last question:  if there were no "x" attached to the discrete variable $n$, then does that mean we wouldn't have a Riemann sum, because the variable $n$, by itself, cannot convert to the continuous variable $t$?  So, not only must the mesh of the partition go to zero, but we also need the size of the discrete variable to also shrink to zero, too.  Is my thinking correct?  It's hard to make the connection from background reading to a real example, when online sources available for Riemann sums / integration, e.g.,

Comment: Wikipedia, give lots of background reading, with little concrete examples.  So I just want to make sure that I understand how to convert to an integral legitimately.  Thanks @robjohn,

Comment: @User001: The integration starts at $0$ when we are bounding the sum above, and starts at $x^2$ when we are bounding the sum below. The domain of integration is the whole real line since the sum goes to infinity. We are essentially mapping $t\mapsto nx^2$ and $\mathrm{d}t\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @User001: If you look at the final bound, one could simply set $x=1$ to see what happens without the "$x$". $$\pi-2\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(1+n)\sqrt{n}}\le\pi$$ It is still a Riemann Sum, but not a rescalable one that one would use to compute an integral.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your help @robjohn :-)

Answer (score 3):

For small $x$ we can distinguish the initial part of the series with $nx^2\leq 1$ and the rest.  For computational convenience assume that $x=1/m^{1/2}$ for some integer $m$.  The initial part of the series then goes from $n=1$ up to $n=1/x^2$. We then have $1+nx^2\leq 2$ in that part of the series, and so the sum is $\geq (x/2)\sum_{n=1}^{1/x^2} n^{-1/2}$, which is $$\geq {x\over 2}\int_1^{1/x^2} y^{-1/2}\, dy= xy^{1/2}|_1^{1/x^2}=x(1/x-1)=1-x.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ForgotAlot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement ForgotALot's nice answer, here is a proof that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}$$
converges when $\alpha = 1/2$, so that the question makes sense. Note that $1 + nx^2 > nx^2$, so for $x \neq 0$ we have
$$\frac{1}{1+nx^2} < \frac{1}{nx^2}$$
Consequently,
$$\left|\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{\alpha}}\right| < \frac{|x|}{n^{1 + \alpha}x^2} = \frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}|x|}$$
For fixed $x \neq 0$, the sum of the right-hand side is finite provided that $\alpha > 0$, and this includes $\alpha = 1/2$, so this shows that
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^{1/2}}$$
converges absolutely for all $x \neq 0$. Also, since the terms are all zero at $x=0$, we also have $F(0) = 0$.

Since ForgotALot's answer shows that $F(x) \geq 1-x$ for $x > 0$, we can certainly rule out $\lim_{x \to 0}F(x) = 0$.

However, this doesn't necessarily imply that $\lim_{x \to 0}F(x) > 0$, because (as far as I can tell) it hasn't yet been established that $\lim_{x \to 0}F(x)$ exists. I'll edit if I can prove this.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help @Bungo - really appreciate it!  :-)